# Using mySQL syntax within html script tag

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, materialize

I have a mySQL database. Let's say I have a table with columns name, number, and location. I want to be able to call {{name}} and {{number}} within a script tag in an html file. For ex. if the id of an input field is {{name}}. But I have not found a way to be able to do this. Any suggestions?

```
// where switchEdit{{name}} is the id of an input field
// this didn't work and i knew it wouldn't; i have no ideas

switchEdit{{name}}.addEventListener('change', function() {
...
```